# Leibniz integration rule reference

Tags: reference-request

I'm looking for a nice reference for the "Leibniz integral rule".
Do you know one?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Might be a bit late, but one reference that looks nice is

Differentiation Under the Integral Sign

Harley Flanders

The American Mathematical Monthly , Vol. 80, No. 6 (Jun. - Jul., 1973) , pp. 615-627

Published by: Mathematical Association of America

Article DOI: 10.2307/2319163

Article Stable URL: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2319163

Avaiable at jstor

Answer (score -1):

I think [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) is what your'e looking for

Comment: yes, but do you know a book or a article where I can find it? I'm interested in the particular case of integrating w.r.t a measure?

Comment: There is a reference at the end of the wikipedia page. Also the theorem is discussed in Rudin's principles of mathematical analysis  (no measures are mentioned though)

Comment: thank you, you are right neither Rudin or the wiki's page reference mention measures.

Comment: I gave a -1 because Wikipedia is certainly not a nice reference to quote.